# Querying over nested assets in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to write a specific query for my Hyperledger Composer app. Below, I have 2 assets and a transaction. `Asset1` has a field called `contents`, which is an array of type `Asset2`. The associated code is below:

```
namespace org.acme.biznet

asset Asset1 identified by Asset1Id {
    o String Asset1Id
    --> Asset2[] contents
}

asset Asset2 identified by Asset2Id {
    o String Asset2Id
}

transaction Transact {
    --> Asset1 asset1
}
```

I want to select all instances of `Transact` where the associated `Asset1` has a specified `Asset2` inside. The closest solution I came to the query below, which did not work.

```
query GetTransactionsThatHaveAsset2 {
    description: ""
    statement: 
        SELECT org.acme.biznet.Transact
            WHERE (asset1.contents CONTAINS (Asset2Id == _$propId))
}
```

The thing is, I have also written the query below.

```
query GetAsset1sThatHaveAsset2 {
    description: ""
    statement: 
        SELECT org.acme.biznet.Asset1 
            WHERE (contents CONTAINS (Asset2Id == _$propId))
}
```

This query behaves as intended, but it's selecting over `Asset1`. I want to select over `Transact`. How would I write this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you can't presently nest the query like you propose, nested named queries are not currently implemented in Composer (CouchDB is not a relational DB, and hence Composer query language can't translate the nested query presently to be translated to CouchDB) 2) `Transact` is a transaction - it contains a relationship identifier(s) you defined in your model, not the nested data stored in the related asset. You would have to define a query that searches for all transactions that matches the `asset1` identifier field you passed to the trxn - then in your code, you can check  `transact.asset1.contents` contains the 'something' (passed in to the trxn too?) using a javascript match - quite straightforward). Alternatively, you could use the REST API filters (loopback filters as opposed to queries) where (form your app code) you can resolve the relationships of transaction (Transact) back to asset1 (and its contents) using the REST call with filter eg 
`{"where":{"asset1":"resource:org.acme.net.Asset1#1"}, "include":"resolve"}` . Hope this helps, maybe its nesting you're looking for exclusively..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have these assets

```
// Define assets
asset Product identified by productId {
    o String productId
    o String description
    o String serialNumber  
    o String modelNumber
    o String status // TRANSFERED, RECEIVED, RECLAMED
    o DateTime joinTime 
    --> Trader previousOwner 
    --> Trader currentOwner
    --> Trader newOwner
}

// Trade, moves product from to a new owner. 
transaction Trade {
  --> Product product
  --> Trader newOwner
  o String trade_type
}
```

---

Executing a trade transaction results in the record:

---

```
{
 "$class": "org.sp.network.Trade",
 "product": "resource:org.sp.network.Product#123",
 "newOwner": "resource:org.sp.network.Trader#6694",
 "trade_type": "Trade",
 "transactionId": "e39a86ed4748a3ab73b5e9c023f6bb0ca025098af09b8b5b2dca8f5f7ef0db67",
 "timestamp": "2019-06-13T12:04:20.180Z"
}
```

---

And to query all Trade transactions that contain a product is

```
 query ProductPath{
    description: "Selete all Trade transactions for a specific ProductId"
    statement:
        SELECT org.sp.network.Trade 
          WHERE (_$productId==product)
}
```

---

Using the rest server: the value of `_$productId` is `resource:org.sp.network.Product#123`

[image]